# Java class design - Too many if conditions

Tags: java

My code snippet is as follows :

```
public void execute(Parameters params) {
    Long requestType = params.getRequestType();
    // Based on the requestType the name of the project would be different
    getName(requestType); 
    // Same as above
    getDescription(requestType) 
    // Project here is a collection of different requests
    Long projectId = createProject(name, description) 
    RequestContents requestContents = params.getRequestContents();
    for(RequestContent requestcontent : requestcontents) {
        Long requestId = createRequest(name, description, projectId);
        updateRequest(requestId, requestContent1);
    }
    // Based on the  requestType, mail content would differ 
    String mailContent = getMailContent(requestType, projectId) 
    sendMail(mailContent); 
}
```

The output of functions `sendMail`, `createProject`, `createRequest` depends on the `requestType`, and so these functions would end up having multiple `if-else` conditions. 
What is the right way to model this class, to avoid this ?

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to create an abstract class `AbstractRequest` having abstract methods `sendMail`, `createProject` etc and then have several concrete subclasses `RequestType1` `RequestType2` etc each having different implementation of `sendMail`  etc. I guess they call it a Strategy pattern.

Comment: They actually call it polymorphism: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Comment: Instead of the request, I would refactor the class containing the exectue() method above.

Comment: @jordan002 Thanks, patterns are hard for me. So you mean this is not a Strategy pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Use [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch):

```
public class Sender {

    public void sendMail(RequestType1 requestType, String mailContent) {
        // some impl
    }
    public void sendMail(RequestType2 requestType, String mailContent) {
        // some impl
    }
    public void sendMail(RequestType3 requestType, String mailContent) {
        // some impl
    }
}
```

then

```
sender.sendMail(requestType, mailContent);
```

The actual method invoked is determined at runtime based on the type of the `requestType` object. Not an "if" in sight.

You could simply implement these methods locally, but that would be confusing and hard to read. Better to split out this concern into a separate class.

Comment: -1 I would apply simple polymorphism here, not method overloading. I would go for a request interface with methods sendMail, createProject, etc. and a factory that instantiate the correct concrete type based on the parameters.

Comment: @ewernli in this case, it would be better to **write an answer** before voting down.

Comment: @ewernli So that opinion makes this answer "not useful" does it? ("Not useful" is what downvoting is meant to indicate - not that you feel there's a better answer)

Comment: Are RequestType1, 2, and 3 subclasses of RequestType?

Comment: @BheshGurung They don't have to be

Comment: I've never heard of double dispatch before so this answer was useful for me. I'm trying to understand if there's more to the double dispatch then just a way of regrouping the code

Comment: not very useful without showing how double dispatched is implemented for this case.

Comment: @Bohemian Your answer is not useful for multiple reasons: 1) It's quite a clear case for simple OO polymorphism. The added complexity of anything else should be justified with respect to this simplest solution otherwise it indicates over-engineering 2) Your answer is simply misleading. What you show looks rather like *overloading* (which won't work) than an implementation of *double dispatch*.

Answer (score 0):

If the requestType is a finite set of String values, you can create a matching Enum for it.

```
enum RequestType{
    type1,type2,...;
}
```

Then, you can transform the if-else to a more compact switch-case:

```
switch (RequestType.valueOf(requestType)){
    case type1:
        ....
    break;
    case type2:
        ...
    break;
    ...
    default:
}
```

From the code, requestType is a long, you can directly switch on it:

```
switch (requestType){
    case type1:
        ....
    break;
    case type2:
        ...
    break;
    ...
    default:
}
```

Comment: If you are using Java7, you can directly switch on a String without having to pass through an enum;

Comment: The requestType is Long not a String.

Answer (score 0):

why not put the if-else condition in the execute() method itself and based on that call the other methods and pass the relevant parameters. This way you will be creating generic functions of sendmail, createproject, createrequest.